# No water coming out of kitchen faucet!

Tags: plumbing, water, kitchens, faucet, sink

Yesterday, our kitchen faucet suddenly stopped working. Water pressure has always been fine, but now there is only a trickle. It's a single handle faucet and both the hot and cold will not work. I have a reverse osmosis water filter next to it that still works fine, and I know the shutoff valves are open. I cleaned the aerator and even took off the sprayer, and still very little water comes out from the hose, so I don't think it's a clogged sprayer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you have flexible piping running to the bottom of the faucet:

1. turn off both the hot & cold the water supplies
2. disconnect the piping from the faucet
3. aim the hot water pipe into a bucket and turn the hot water back on (quickly turn it off, of course)
4. repeat for the cold water side

If you're getting water in the bucket, the faucet's the problem. If it's the faucet, you can start working to disassemble it to see where the problem is or simply replace it.