# Why is no water coming out of my new kitchen faucet?

Tags: faucet

Bought a Kingston single hole kitchen faucet. Took out old faucet and installed new one. Hooked up 3/8 to 1/2 braided supply lines. I tested the lines to be sure water came out, which it did, then attached supply lines to faucet.

Everything fits fine but when I opened the water lines again after hooking up the faucet, no water comes out faucet. I did turn the faucet handle 90* to accommodate the beveled  breakfast bar.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you forget to open the water shutoff valves back up after the installation?

Comment: Need model number of faucet (because idk what that 90 turn is about), and of the supply lines. I suspect they have integral shut-offs like the ones for ice makers. Or you didn't *remove before instillation* the dust cover inside the fitting.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62460/no-water-coming-out-of-kitchen-faucet?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Is there an aerator in the faucet outlet? If so, remove it, and try turning on again. These often get clogged from debris you shake lose in the lines during installation.

Some faucets also require you to remove part of the valve after installation to flush the lines, then re-install. Check the instructions for your faucet. If you could post the make and model of your faucet, we could look at the instructions and tell you more as well.

Comment: Check the instructions for your faucet, +1. Could also require you to remove a shipping-part of the faucet [*before*] installation.

Answer (score 2):

I just installed a bathroom faucet, but it could apply to your kitchen faucet.  There was a small plastic piece inside the faucet itself that got clogged with small debris.  Debri was caused from simply chnaging hoses and turning water on/off.  The plastic piece was smaller than a thumbnail, and shaped like an ashtray, so the miniscule debris was enough to clog.  I shut off the water and disassembled the faucet from the top down to uncover the culprit.